# Convolution of tempered distribution($K$) and gaussian. if $K = K*e^{-\pi |x|^2}$, then $K$ is first degree polynomial.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, convolution, harmonic-analysis, gaussian

> Q : I need to prove that if $K$ is tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying:
> \begin{equation}
> K = K*e^{-\pi |x|^2}
> \end{equation}
> then $K$ is first degree polynomial. mean $K(x) = Ax + b$

Remark: The question was changed. The original was to prove that if $K = K * e^{-\pi |x|^2}$ then $K$ is constant, which is false.

The first thing I did is to apply fourier transform on both sides to work with multiplication instead of convolution. and I got $\hat{K} = e^{-\pi |x|^2} \hat{K}$.

I succeeded to prove $\hat{K}$ is supported at the origin and by theorem 1.7 at page 110, from Stein and Shakarchi functional analysis(Can't find the pdf online) or theorem 6.25 at page 165 from [Rudin Functional analysis](https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/functional-analysis-_-rudin-2th.pdf):
\begin{equation}
\hat{K} =\sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} a_{\alpha} \partial^{\alpha}\delta
\end{equation}.

Now, if I apply the inverse fourier transform I get that $K$ is a polynomial.

The solution will arise if I will prove that if $p$ is a polyomial in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ satisfying
$p*e^{-\pi |x|^2} = p$, then $p$ is constant.

It sounds true(which is not, please see the comments) but I think it is kind of "ugly" to prove and I am pretty sure that there is another way for me to continue.

Hot to continue?

Thanks :)

Comment: So $(e^{-\pi|x|^2}-1)\hat K = 0.$ What does this imply for $\hat K$?

Comment: Is it actually true? If $d=1$ and $K$ is the multiplication operator corresponding to the polynomial $p(x)=x$, then $$(p*e^{-\pi|\cdot|^2})(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(x-y)e^{-\pi y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y=x=p(x).$$ This also seems to be suggesting that some lengthy or dirty argument is unavoidable.

Comment: @md2perpe I was thinking to continue to work with the fourier transform but,
I already proved that it is supported at the origin, and any distribution, $F$ which supported at the origin satisfying that $e^{-\pi |x|^2}F = F$ so I dont think I have something else to do.
Also $$e^{-\pi |x|^2} - 1$ is not schwartz function, so I dont think that I it is defined.

Comment: @SangchulLee It is question from my homework. so I hope it is true :)
But thanks to you I know that the proposition I wanted to prove is false.

Comment: In fact, if $p$ is any [harmonic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_polynomial), then it is invariant under the evolution by heat equation, and so, $p=p*e^{-\pi|\cdot|^2}$ holds as well. I suspect that the converse is also true, but I have no good idea to prove it right now.

Comment: @SangchulLee maybe the main clain is false?

Comment: I think so. (Most of all, we have counter-examples!)

Comment: In $d=1$ it is possible to show that the most general solution admitted is $K(x)=Ax+B$, which is a trivial version of the polynomials suggested by @SangchulLee . The proof I did is pure brute force and consists of looking at the image of arbitrary degree mononomials under the transformation and showing that $\{1,x\}$ are eigenvectors of the convolution, while all the others are not and that there exist no linear transformations that can make them eigenvectors of the operator (the eigenspace of eigenvalue 1 is 2-dimensional) which suggests the conclusion.

Comment: @shestak. $e^{-\pi |x|^2} - 1$ is not a Schwartz function, but it is a tempered distribution.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Last change. Indeed $d = 1$.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the problem is false. In fact, let $p$ be any harmonic polynomial. Then by noting that

$$ \Phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{d/2}}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}} $$

is the fundamental solution of the heat equation $\partial_t\Phi = \Delta\Phi$, we have

$$ \partial_t(p*\Phi) = p*(\partial_t\Phi)=p*(\Delta\Phi)=(\Delta p)*\Phi=0. $$

Together with $ p(x) = \lim_{t\to 0} (p*\Phi)(x,t) $, this implies that $p = p*\Phi$. Then plugging $t = \frac{1}{4\pi}$ proves

$$ p = p * e^{-\pi|\cdot|^2}. \tag{*} $$

---

I suspect that the converse is also true, since the condition $\text{(*)}$ implies that $p(x) = (p*\Phi)(x,\frac{n}{4\pi})$ for any integer $n \geq 1$. This surely sounds like another line of interesting question, although I have no good idea to prove this right now.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
The question was changed to proved that K is liner polynomial(affine)

Comment: @shestak, it is true that the harmonic polynomials for $d=1$ are polynomials of degree at most one. Even for $d=2$, however, the harmonic polynomials are precisely the real/imaginary parts of complex polynomials in $z=x+iy$, and so, they can assume arbitrarily high degree. For instance, $p(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ works!

Comment: Thanks again.
About the inverse, correct me if I am wrong, but if condition $(*)$ is satisfied, then since p is a polynomial at $x$(does not depend on $t$), then
$\Delta_x(p*\Phi) = \dotsb=\partial_t(p*\Phi) = (\partial_t p) * \Phi = 0$.
since this is true for all $t$ we can plugging $ t = \frac{1}{4\pi} $ to recieve that $\Delta p = 0$

Comment: Last change in the exercise. $ d = 1 $. Thanks

Comment: @shestak, We cannot conclude that $\partial_t(p*\Phi)$ because $t$ is not the variable involved in convolution. Indeed, if $p$ is not a harmonic polynomial then this expression can change in time.